# Using context within an intent

Tags: android, android-intent, intentservice, commonsware-cwac

I am using the `WakefulIntentService` 3rd party `IntentService` implementation.

Basically I have a few planned tasks and I can only run them here:

```
protected void doWakefulWork(Intent intent) {
    System.out.println("This is where I do the work for every 10 secs!"); 
}
```

However this only passes intent, what I want to do is able to use `Context` for various reasons such as `getSystemService`, `openOrCreateDatabase` etc. which are available within a `Context`. So how can I access `context` from an intent? If this is not possible, how can I do tasks like connecting to a database?

Answer (score 2):

An `IntentService` is-a `Service` and a `Service` is-a `Context`. So just use `YourIntentService.this` where a `Context` is needed.

Answer (score 2):

context is a reference to current object . Use `YourServiceName.this`. As every Service is a context as well.